# Songbook text processing: Repeat chord lines for recurrent parts automatically?

Tags: music, word-processor

With written-down songs in the form of lyrics together with chord names,
the chord names are often left out for recurrent parts.
(Due to limited paper space - you try to minimize the need for turning pages while performing a song).

However, this is inconvenient, when it comes to sight-reading. One must frequently jump between the verses with the eyes to keep track of the chord progression **and** the lyrics.

Now, I'm looking for any tool, library or script that processes existing text files and tries to intelligently put the correct missing chord line above a lyric line.

A syllable-precise positioning isn't possible without the melody, but is not necessary anyway. Automatic part guessing might be the tricky part. The output isn't needed to be perfect, but make life easier.

Comment: What does your input file(s) look like?

Answer (score 2):

A friend and I have created [Chordastic](http://www.chordastic.com) that can help you. It has a feature that repeats the chords on the same lyrics while you enter the chord.

This way you could

- load the file using the text editor or song import (if it's Chordpro file),
- put the chords only at the first verse and
- watch the rest of the chords filled by automatically.

The software is free of charge for most of it's features and with no time limitation.

Comment: Thanks for this interesting proposal. I've giving it a try. It seems that the chords are only "filled by automatically" if the lyrics are the same. This may be true for the chorus, but not for verses.

Comment: Well yes, I cannot think of a way to do this automatically otherwise.

Comment: How about a first guess of the chord position? A correction looks pretty easy with your tool (drag and drop).

Comment: If we provide fuzzy logic in this we will get in trouble with most of our clients. We prefer to be precise than fuzzy, after all we are just an editor and not a composing software